# ArrayList как поле класса. Как заполнить?

Tags: java, коллекции, конструктор

Всем привет.

Моя задача заключается в том, чтобы создать
 `class Person (int homeNumber, ArrayList<Integer> mobileNumbers){};`, а затем в main создать объект этого класса.
Проблема состоит в том, что я не знаю, как добавить мобильные номера. Т.е. я пишу в меине `new Person(12345567,...);`, а, что писать на месте точек, не знаю.
Как в лист мобильных номеров добавить 1-2 номера и более? Как к нему обращаться при создании?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrP.add(new Person("Ivanov",123, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))));` -  в main

`this.mNum = mNum;` в конструкторе

Answer (score 1):

В мейне создать ArrayList, добавить ему элементы (если нужно) и передать его в конструктор, как к нему обращаться, зависит от того, какая область видимости этого поля и в каком классе находится мейн.

Comment: ArrayList с мобильными номерами являются полем класса Person, т.е. я считаю, что лист с моб. номерами, объявленный в мейне отдельно, не вполне гармоничный ход (если я правильно понял Ваш ход мысли). У меня  в меине есть лист, но он содержит набор объектов класса Person.
`public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args){
  ArrayList<Person> arrP = new ArrayList<Person>();
  arrP.add(new Person("I",,{123}));
 }
}
public class Person {

 public Person(String surn, int hNum, ArrayList<Integer> mNum) {
  this.surn = surn;
  this.hNum = hNum;
  this.mNum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 }}


Comment: Тогда вам нужно писать:
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Person> arrP = new ArrayList<Person>();
    arrP.add(new Person("I", 1, new ArrayList<Integer>()));
}
Но в этом случае вы сможете добавить только один элемент в 
new ArrayList<Integer>()
В таком виде:
new ArrayList<Integer>().add(12345)

Вам нужно создать, как я говорил выше
ArrayList<Integer> mobs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
mobs.add(1111);
mobs.add(2222);
И потом:
arrP.add(new Person("I", 1, mobs));

Comment: @Cooler, а если у меня не один объект будет, а десятки или сотни, то придется вручную для каждого создать лист?

Comment: что значит вручную, делаете метод, который принимает номера и закидывает в лист. Вызываете его до создания объекта Person. Хотя для меня логичней было бы создать объект Person с пустым листом, а в самом классе Person уже сам метод, который принимает номер и забрасывает в лист. 

В этом случае правильней убрать лист из конструктора и инициализировать его в самом классе.